# Are REST streaming APIs implemented using HTTP Keep-Alive header packets?

Tags: api, rest, http

If I were to send out a HTTP GET request to e.g. the [Shodan REST streaming API](https://developer.shodan.io/api/stream), is this implemented on the server side by periodically sending out HTTP Keep-Alive messages to the client in case there is no new data to be sent out?
Or are there other options/techniques available for implementing REST streaming API endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as an http keepalive message.

The API you link to simply doesn't tell the client in advance how long the response body is, so a client can keep reading the newline-separated messages from what counts as one response until either side decides they're done.

Comment: If I understand correctly:
1. client sends GET request with keep-alive header
2. server responds with data. No periodic message with keep-alive header set are necessary.
3. connection is left open up until either party decides to close the connection.

Comment: Sounds about right. Implementations may vary though.

Comment: Alright, clear, thanks for answering my question!